# Google Chrome fps lag with Nvidia GTX770

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, google-chrome

I'm using the `nvidia 352.63` drivers with a GTX770.

When I open many chrome windows (like 4 or 5 windows) (**not tabs**) the windows' fps start dropping, sometimes reaching 20fps *and it's so annoying*. Chrome's hardware acceleration flag is enabled.

I don't think the card reaches its limits. The memory (2GB) is far from full and the utilisation level is very low also.

Anyone knows a workaround?

Comment: What happens when you disable hardware acceleration? How much RAM does your system have?

Comment: @SuperSluether that doesn't happen with the acceleration disabled but then chrome's graphics are very bad. It uses the cup's integrated graphics .. ram's not a problem either, it's far from full. it's 16 gigs

Comment: Have you solved this issue ? I have same symptoms on Ubuntu 16.04 .

Comment: @Vovan sadly no. Apparently it's a drivers issue. We can't do anything about it. However my workaround is to **minimise** any windows I'm not currentlyh using. This makes the one non-minimised window 60fps in most cases

Comment: @Mina Michael, i wonder why anyone else does not notices this issue. I have the same experience on different computers with GTX670 and GTX1080. We can use Firefox browser, he has no such lags at least.

Comment: btw. I created similar question here some time ago: http://askubuntu.com/questions/816804/chrome-high-gpu-usage-and-low-fps-while-scrolling-the-page

Comment: @Vovan yeah I really wonder why. It's quite an issue. Apparently not much people enable hardware acceleration; they just use chrome with integrated graphics. But it makes browser games choppy and tearing.

Comment: when chrome is under load,all the unity effects is laggy.this is most likely a nvidia driver issue.i dont notice this in noveau driver.

Comment: changing nvidia powermizer to max performance reduces lag.