# 1080 GTX Slow performance Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have installed a new Nvidia 1080 GTX and I tried to install it in Ubuntu 16.04.

1) Installed on other SSD using HDMI (intel)
2) I used `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`
3) Select Nvidia Drivers 367.xx (Open source)

When I opened chrome every other window had lag when resizing and moving around.

Other things I tried:

Downloading the Nvidia driver on their website using a ".run" file (Which give me the login loop error)

I do not know what is going on.

In Windows 10 the GPU works very well. I did benchmarks, heating tests and played high demand GPU games.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: I suggest you reinstall (since you shouldn't install 3 drivers at once) and take a look here http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics

Comment: I already tried and still slow.

Comment: Hi, take a look to my question here http://askubuntu.com/questions/816804/chrome-high-gpu-usage-and-low-fps-while-scrolling-the-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the nVidia proprietary beta driver. Open source drivers, to my knowledge, do not work well currently with Pascal GPUs.

Make sure to select the proprietary driver in Additional Drivers.

If that doesn't work, try disabling all window animations and install CCSM. You might want to tweak some of the OpenGL and Unity settings.

Is the GPU experiencing lag in only Chrome? Do other 3d applications work well? In that case, it could be that Chrome has a compatibility issue.

In that case, go to chrome://flags and enable all flags pertaining to Hardware acceleration. Then go to chrome://gpu and make sure all the flags there have hardware acceleration enabled. You might want to check this out:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/CtKF2BiskT8;context-place=forum/chrome

Comment: thanks for you answer, how do I install the nVidia proprietary beta driver?

Comment: See this page: http://askubuntu.com/questions/795547/ubuntu-16-04-unable-to-boot-with-gtx-1080

Comment: Another question. I tried everything you wrote and the stuff from Google. But there are some apps like for example Spotify which have like a Chrome Framework or something, so if I open that too, the system starts to become slower.

I do have ppa drivers 367 right now.

Comment: If you've installed the latest 367 drivers from the nVidia ppa then everything should be working fine. Does the 1080 game well on linux? If it does, it's possible that other components (CPU, RAM, or even the Ubuntu installation) could be the issue. Do you experience an overall system-slowdown? It's most likely the CPU or RAM in that case.

Comment: I did a benchmark and compared with other benchmarks and everything was fine. I do game a lot on Windows and everything looks fine. 

I have installed ubuntu like 3 times. Do you think that it's something related to Chrome?

Comment: I assume so. Remember, the GTX 1080 is still quite new and quirks may not be worked out yet. I don't have much more advice besides updating all your CPU and GPU drivers. Chrome has issues on my Skylake laptop as well, so Chrome isn't perfect on all devices. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I am using 1080Ti and Ubuntu 17.04. My cursor and typing are both lagged. Besides downloading the driver and going through steps, you can also download CUDA straight - which includes the driver in addition to the CUDA library. There are only need 4 lines of commands following instructions from CUDA download page and type "reboot" to restart the machine!

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1704-9-0-local_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-<version>/7fa2af80.pub
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cuda
reboot
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to indicate where you can get `cuda-repo-ubuntu1704-9-0-local_9.0.176-1_amd64.deb` in your answer.